# CNN give less accuracy when I train it on more class

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have a CNN for skin diseases and when I train it on ~5K picture I got 92% network accuracy and 83% val acc but when I train the same network with 25K picture in the same data shape I got 0.08% acc 
*the data shape: clinical images for Patients hands, faces, etc.
I train the network with augmentation that I found online using ImageDataGenerator

```
model = Sequential()
# 1st layer
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(img_rows, img_cols,img_channels)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),data_format = "channels_last"))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),data_format = "channels_last"))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),data_format = "channels_last"))

#last
model.add(Flatten())  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

Comment: were you using the same Image augmentation when you trained on 5k images? ```ImageDataGenerator``` may not work the same way you think it works, you can read this [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/07/08/keras-imagedatagenerator-and-data-augmentation/)

Comment: yes, I used the same augmentation but even when I trained the model without augmentation I got 70% acc on the 5k and 0.07 on the 25k

Comment: try to change the image size on the 25k dataset.